# How to change iPhone app to support iPad

Tags: ios

Can anybody tell me the how to change the present iPhone app to support iPad?

```
MyController *controller = nil;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyiPadNib" bundle:nil];
else
    controller = [[MyController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyiPodNib" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I've tried this, what are the other changes I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a universal app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603169/how-to-make-a-universal-app)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Target settings -> General -> Deployment info -> Devices -> change to Universal. Now you can able to run your application in iPad also.